Create two arrays based on duplicates column rows from in PySpark
I am using PySpark and have a dataframe the has two columns a and b, there is only one value, per column/row in the dataframe to start. There can (but won't always) be duplicate values in b across rows. The objective is to transform the dataframe to have an array of all of the overlapping values in b in a single row with an array of the corresponding values of a, removing the old rows during the process. Rows where b does not overlap with another row should remain unaltered.
If this was my data:
data = [
 ('00003-01', 4249300705),
 ('00003-01', 4242100870),
 ('00004-10', 4242100870),
 ('00004-10', 4242180791),
 ('00005-01', 4249301111),
 ('00005-01', 4242184444),
 ('00006-10', 4242184444)
]

columns = ["a", "b"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=columns)

After running the method, df.show(truncate=False) would be:
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------
|a                      |b                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------
|[00003-01, 00004-10]   |[4249300705, 4242180791, 4242100870]            |
|[00005-01, 00006-10]   |[4249301111, 4242184444]                        |
+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------

I've tried a few ways using joins but it seems like when there is more than two instances where they need to be meshed together into one row (not ruling this out - I've just had no luck), this method does not work very well. I think it could be accomplished with some nested loops (and I'm not totally against that if it's the only way) but I feel like there must be something more clever and efficient to solve this.

Check below code.
df
.groupBy("a")
.agg(collect_list("b").alias("b"))
.withColumn(
    "b", 
    expr("""
        SORT_ARRAY(
            ARRAY_DISTINCT(
                FLATTEN(
                    FILTER(
                        COLLECT_LIST(b) OVER(ORDER BY 1), 
                        e -> e == b OR ARRAYS_OVERLAP(e, b)
                    )
                )
            ), 
            FALSE
        )
    """)
)
.groupBy("b")
.agg(collect_list("a").as("a"))
.select("a", "b")
.show(5, False)

+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|a                   |b                                   |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|[00003-01, 00004-10]|[4249300705, 4242180791, 4242100870]|
|[00005-01, 00006-10]|[4249301111, 4242184444]            |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+


My session is getting hung trying this. Probably a resource issue on my end?

Not sure, how much big is your dataset..?

A bit over 700k rows. The function runs fine, but when I try to show or export I run into memory issues. Which makes me think it could be an issues with the code, but still poking around.

See .. I have used groupBy function two times to get desired result..groupBy function will shuffle data and it requires more memory..try to use cache wherever is possible to speedup execution..

Any specific suggestion?
Current session configs: {'conf': {'spark.executor.memory': '32G', 'spark.executor.cores': '16', 'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled': 'true', 'spark.driver.memory': '32G'}, 'driverMemory': '14G', 'driverCores': 4, 'executorMemory': '14G', 'executorCores': 4, 'numExecutors': 3
It's been a few years since I have revisited spark so apologies if a noob question.

OH, cache the dataframe, this seems to help, looks like I'm facing some GC errors now.
2024-04-24T01:48:00.504+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 3466414K->1006K(4127744K)] 4429655K->1030007K(13914624K), 0.0544217 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.03, real=0.06 secs] 

Just want to understand requirement ..How many columns ? Why do you want to do this way ?

It's for our data science guys model, the way we collect the data from the public resource does not aggregate them. But it is important that we know which ones are connected to one another in order to implement the model. I'm 100% open to other suggestion on how to achieve this. Let me know if that helps explain or if I can elaborate. Thank you very much for your help.

Would it make more sense to write it some sort of json? I'm trying to cast my arrays into strings like this:
def array_to_string(arr):
if arr is None:
return "[]"
return '[' + ', '.join(str(x) for x in arr) + ']'
